# Drupal preprocess a commerce function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to preprocess a function from the module "commerce pricing attributes".

Here is the function :

```
function commerce_pricing_attributes_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {...}
```

I don't know how to preprocess this (if it's possible).

This function create some element in the back-office and the thing I want to do is to give a color to these elements in function of the type of the option the element is. If it's an insurance option there is a color, if it's a room option another color.

I try to do this with an alter like this :
 `function my_module_field_widget_commerce_pricing_attributes_custom_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {...}`

But I can't have all the information I need (the type of the option).

Is there any way to preprocess the function so I can use all the values they use in their module ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this hook : [hook_field_widget_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7.x)

It allow you to override (or add) widget applied to a field

```
function my_module_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  if ($context['field']['type'] == 'mytype') { // you can use another condition on field name or whatever 

    // Loop through the element children (there will always be at least one).
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key => $child) {
      // Add the new process function to the element
      $element[$key]['#process'][] = 'my_custom_callback_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function my_custom_callback_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form){
// do your stuff
  return $element;
 }
```

NB : dump variables to target exactly you want if you don't know structre of them

Comment: I don't know if you can help me with that but the problem now is that I can't know the type of the option the widget is, I think i can achieve this if I can get ALL the options possible for a product and compare them to my widget, but I don't find any function with drupal commerce who can give me the list of the options possibles

Comment: dump variables `$context` and see structure to identify your field when your are on form

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do but the problem is that the context, form_state and element doesn't have what I need to sort the type of the option. I'm on this since two days now and I can't find a solution