# Drupal commerce - Get all options from an option set

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have a drupal commerce website and I need to retrieve all options that are existing for my products. All of these options are in an option set called 'defaut'.

My problem is that I can't find a way to get all these options (I need to check if a checkbox is checked in each of the options settings).

A second way I can do this is to get the form values of the field name of the option, I have all the field names but I don't find any way to retrieve the values from these field_names

I try to search where this can be but doesn't find since i'm on this (two days now), no trace on the database, no methods to get them, i'm lost...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal preprocess a commerce function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382895/drupal-preprocess-a-commerce-function)

Comment: That's not that but I finally found my solution